# Antrl4: Matching '\r\n' and '\n' as one symbol

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I'm trying to limit number of empty lines between blocks to .

```
EOL:
   '\r'?
   '\n'
   '\r'? 
   '\n'?
   SPACE*
```

Is there a way to match '\n' and '\r\n' as a one symbol, like '\R' (linebreak) in Perl 5.
Or ignore '\r' completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Lexer rules result in a single "symbol" (in ANTLR they are referred to as tokens).

The typical way of match EOL in Antlr would be something like:

```
EOL: '\r?\n';
```

this would match an optional carriage return followed by a line feed.

This would match `\r\n` or `\n`

It's pretty customary to put whitespace into a separate rule with a `-> skip` directive or a `-> channel(HIDDNE)` directive.

if you're trying to coalesce end of line whitespace and multiple blank lines, try:

```
EOL:   '\r'? '\n' (' '* '\r'? '\n')*;
```

this will generate a token for trailing whitespace and any subsequent empty lines and their line terminators.

lexer grammar sample:

```
lexer grammar eol
    ;

ALPHA: [A-Za-z]+;
EOL:   '\r'? '\n' (' '* '\r'? '\n')*;
```

sample input file:

```
ANB



G
KL








ZZ
```

```
➜ grun eol tokens -tokens < eol.txt
[@0,0:2='ANB',<ALPHA>,1:0]
[@1,3:6='\n\n\n\n',<EOL>,1:3]
[@2,7:7='G',<ALPHA>,5:0]
[@3,8:8='\n',<EOL>,5:1]
[@4,9:10='KL',<ALPHA>,6:0]
[@5,11:19='\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n',<EOL>,6:2]
[@6,20:21='ZZ',<ALPHA>,15:0]
[@7,22:21='<EOF>',<EOF>,15:2]
```